# What causes unchecked warning in nested generic?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings, unchecked

When I use a nested generic in a method, there is an unchecked warning. Why is that?

```
package test;

public class subc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer aa[] = new Integer[10];
        infunction(aa);
        // Not Warning , Use genericTest !!!!!!!!!!!
        Integer[] abc = genericTest(aa, aa.getClass());
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Integer a = abc[0];
    }

    public static <T> T[] genericTest(T[] aa, Class<? extends T[]> class1) {
        return aa;
    }

    public static <T> T[] infunction(T[] aa) {
        // Warning, Use genericTest( unchecked ) !!!!!!!!!!
        T[] result = (T[]) genericTest(aa, aa.getClass());
        return result;
    }
}
```

If I modify the method, there is no warning:

```
public static <T> T[] genericTest(T[] aa) {
    return aa;
}
```

So why am I getting a warning in the first code block and not the second?

Comment: Why `Class<? extends T[]>`? You could just say `Class<? extends T>` or better yet `Class<T>` (in your `genericTest` method).

Comment: just test code, and i copied, Arrays.copyOf

Comment: public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
        T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
            ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
            : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                         Math.min(original.length, newLength));
        return copy;
    }
i just change simple case

Answer (score 0):

The unchecked cast is the `(T[])` cast you see explicitly written in your code there. `T[]` is not a reifiable type, and therefore a cast to it is not completely checked at runtime.

I'm guessing you added a cast when the code without the cast didn't compile. So the real question is why `T[] result = genericTest(aa, aa.getClass());` doesn't compile.

This is because `aa.getClass()` returns type `Class<? extends Object[]>`. The `.getClass()` method's actual compile-time return type (as described in its documentation) is `Class<? extends |X|>`, where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression `.getClass()` is called on. Here, `aa` has type `T[]`, whose erasure is `Object[]`, so `aa.getClass()` returns type `Class<? extends Object[]>`. (The reasons for the return type of `.getClass()` I will not go into here.)

Since `genericTest`'s second parameter has type `Class<? extends T[]>` (in terms of `genericTest`'s `T`) and `aa.getClass()` has type `Class<? extends Object[]>`, the only valid choice for `T` in the call `genericTest(aa, aa.getClass())` is if `T` is `Object`. Therefore, `genericTest(aa, aa.getClass())` returns type `Object[]`, which cannot be assigned to `T[]`.